# Remove Old Kernel to free disk space

Tags: 14.04, kernel

My system has old Ubuntu kernels but I am unable to remove them. How can I remove my old kernel to free my hard disk. Here are some outputs of commands I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 265 not upgraded.
After this operation, 193 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216178 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-12-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img.old 
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
Purging configuration files for linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/prerm.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
dkms: removing: bcmwl 6.30.223.141+bdcom (3.13.0-29-generic) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.141+bdcom
Kernel:  3.13.0-29-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
```

Also,

```
$ depmod
DKMS: uninstall completed.
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-16-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-12-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
The link /vmlinuz.old is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link vmlinuz.old 
 you may need to re-run your boot loader[grub]
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-29-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic
```

I tried

```
abhay@abhay-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7       7.7G  6.6G  776M  90% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.5G   12K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           295M  1.5M  293M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G  156K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Then on retrying,

```
abhay@abhay-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic'
```

Also,

```
abhay@abhay-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic'
```

And,

```
abhay@abhay-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ du -sh /var/tmp
4.0K    /var/tmp
```

Answer (score 6):

**ubuntu-tweak** is the better solution for a beginner.

**installation**:  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

**removing old kernel using *ubuntu-tweak*** :

- use the `start janitor` button in the ubuntu-tweak window
- click on `old kernel` check box
- select the old kernels
- click `clean`

[image]

Comment: That is simply the best answer for someone new to Ubuntu

Comment: This solution is not suitable for server users.